# Jacobson radical as direct summand

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a local ring with unity. Then when can we say that $J$, the Jacobson radical of $R$, is an $R/J$-module? And when is $R$ isomorphic to $J\oplus R/J$ as $R/J$-modules?

Comment: Why would you want $J$ to be an $R/J$-module (i.e. an $R/J$-vector space)?

Comment: For instance, when $R$ contains a field isomorphic to $R/J$. (The first question has also a positive answer when $J^2=0$.)